# C# parallel step through execution graph

Tags: c#, graph-theory

Imagine a graph of execution where each process may have 0..many required processes to execute and conversely must be executed in order to execute 0..many successive processes.

What would that algorithm look like in C#?

This is what I have so far:

```
while(Steps.Any(s => !s.Complete))
    Parallel.ForEach(Steps.Where(s => !s.Started), step =>
    {
        if(step.Parents.All(p=>p.Complete))
            step.Execute();
    });
```

I'm not even sure if this works yet.

Was wondering about whether I'm even going down the right path or what.

Anyone know any good literature on the subject of execution graphs.

Comment: what do you mean by 'conversely'? The statement does not seem converse by the way it's phrased.

Comment: It has 'parents' that are required to run and conversely has 'children' that require it to execute before they can.  If I'm using that word incorrectly I apologize.  I'm trying to use it as a contraposition

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I'd first start with a representation of the Tree. In this, each node will contain a Task (your process).

```
    public sealed class Node
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public Action Action { get; }
        public LinkedList<Node> Descendants { get; }

        public Node(string name, Action action)
        {
            Name = name;
            Action = action;
            Descendants = new LinkedList<Node>();
        }

        public void AddDescendant(Node node) => Descendants.AddLast(node);
    }
```

Once you have this, you can create a simple tree:

```
    public Node CreateTree()
    {
        Node root = new Node("root", () => Console.WriteLine("1"));

        Node gen1_1 = new Node("gen1_1", () => Console.WriteLine("2"));
        Node gen1_2 = new Node("gen1_2", () => Console.WriteLine("3"));

        Node gen2_1 = new Node("gen2_1", () => Console.WriteLine("4"));
        Node gen2_2 = new Node("gen2_2", () => Console.WriteLine("5"));
        Node gen2_3 = new Node("gen2_3", () => Console.WriteLine("6"));
        Node gen2_4 = new Node("gen2_4", () => Console.WriteLine("7"));


        root.AddDescendant(gen1_1);
        root.AddDescendant(gen1_2);

        gen1_1.AddDescendant(gen2_1);
        gen1_1.AddDescendant(gen2_2);
        gen1_2.AddDescendant(gen2_3);
        gen1_2.AddDescendant(gen2_4);

        return root;
    }
```

Then the simplest function ever, to create tasks out of the actions and run them in an async way:

```
    public async Task ExecuteAll(Node root)
    {
        await Task.Run(root.Action);
        await Task.WhenAll(root.Descendants.Select(ExecuteAll));
    }
```

And this is the test:

```
    [Test]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        var root = CreateTree();
        Console.WriteLine("start");
        await ExecuteAll(root);
        Console.WriteLine("finish");
    }
```

[image]